# Access Current NHibernate Session in Castle Windsor IOC Container

Tags: fluent-nhibernate, inversion-of-control, castle-windsor, quartz.net, sharp-architecture

I am trying to access my current nhibernate session using IOC from within a running Quartz.net Job and every time it comes back as null stating the following:

> 'NHibernateSession.Current' threw an exception of type 'SharpArch.Domain.PreconditionException' NHibernate.ISession  SharpArch.Domain.PreconditionException}. An ISessionStorage has not been configured

Here is my current code setup.  I cannot figure out for the life of me how to setup my IOC so that the NHibernate ISession within my IScheduledMessageQueries query is set correctly.  The Quartz triggers are working correctly, I just cannot access the ISession to call my queries from within the Job.  Any help and/or advice?

Global.cs Code:

```
protected virtual void InitializeServiceLocator()
{
    _container = new WindsorContainer(new XmlInterpreter()).Install(new WebWindsorInstaller());
    StartQuartzScheduler();            
    ComponentRegistrar.AddComponentsTo(_container);
    ServiceLocator.SetLocatorProvider(() => new WindsorServiceLocator(_container));

    DependencyResolver.SetResolver(new WindsorDependencyResolver(_container));
    var activator = new WebApiControllerFactory(_container);
    GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Services.Replace(typeof(IHttpControllerActivator), activator);
}

private static void StartQuartzScheduler()
{
    ISchedulerFactory schedulerFactory = new StdSchedulerFactory();
    IJobFactory jobFactory = new WindsorJobFactory(_container);
    var scheduler = schedulerFactory.GetScheduler();
    scheduler.JobFactory = jobFactory;
    scheduler.Start();
    var sendScheduledMessageJob = new JobDetailImpl("sendScheduledMessageJob", typeof(SendScheduledMessageJob));
    var trigger = new CalendarIntervalTriggerImpl
    {
        StartTimeUtc = DateTime.UtcNow.Subtract(new TimeSpan(1)),
        Name = "Daily Trigger",
        RepeatIntervalUnit = IntervalUnit.Second,
        RepeatInterval = 1
    };
    scheduler.ScheduleJob(sendScheduledMessageJob, trigger);
}

public class SendScheduledMessageJob : IJob
{
    private readonly IScheduledMessageQueries _scheduledMessageQueries;
    public SendScheduledMessageJob(IScheduledMessageQueries scheduledMessageQueries)
    {
        _scheduledMessageQueries = scheduledMessageQueries;
    }

    public void Execute(IJobExecutionContext context)
    {

        var unsentScheduledMessages =
            _scheduledMessageQueries.GetAllUnsentScheduledMessages(DateTime.Now);
    }
}
```

Comment: How are you integrating nHibernate and Windsor?  And remember, nHibernate Session's are NOT thread-safe, but the SessionFactory is.  Perhaps you're trying to use an ISession on a different thread than where it was obtained from?

Comment: Are you using http://nuget.org/packages/Quartz.Windsor ? Have you configured ISessionStorage as the exception says?